# AG-GRID only deleting the first 27 nodes

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react, ag-grid-vue

My grid has around 2500 rows in it and out of those about **400** of them are selected nodes.
So I loop through all the nodes and if their Id is in the Id of those 400 records, I want them to get deleted.
So I wrote this:

```
 allItems.forEach(node => {
     if(selectedItems.includes(node.data.id))
       node.setSelected(false);
   })
```

It works BUT it only deleted **27** rows at a time, instead of deleting all 400 rows. So I have to click my button one more time and it deletes the next 27 records etc.

Why is it behaving like this? How can I change it to delete all those 400 rows at once?

Comment: please post your data.

Answer (score 0):

Your example code is very limited. But why don't you use the grid's internal api to query the selected nodes?

```
this.gridApi.getSelectedNodes().forEach(node => {
  node.setSelected(false);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, I had done that too.  The weird thing is if I say how many item in getSelectedNodes, it does return the correct 400 nodes BUT when it wants to apply the setSelected on them, it still applies to only the first 27 nodes or so !

Comment: I just proved it now too. For testing I increased the height of the grid. So this time more rows showed without needing to scroll down. So when I called my delete method, it deleted MORE than 20 ish that it was deleting before. So it means it has to do something with optimization for the gird, maybe it keeps some sort of buffer of the rows that are visible to the user.

Comment: Hi , just out of curiosity were you using client side row model or server side row model? From what you have mentioned it looks like server side row model.

Answer (score 0):

## Try this:-

To select all rows and delete all selected rows:-

```
  deletedAllSelectedRows() {
          this.gridApi.selectAll(); //select all rows
          const sel = this.gridApi.getSelectedRows();
          this.gridApi.applyTransaction({remove: sel});
      }
```

> Note:-  version 23.1.0 is required for `applyTransaction`. For lower
> version    use  `this.gridApi.updateRowData({remove: sel})`